The uniqueness of the damped Sine-Gordon.
The damped Sine-Gordon equation given :
\begin{equation}
\partial_{tt} u + \alpha \partial_t u - \Delta u + \beta \sin(u) = 0
\end{equation}
for an unknown $u : D \times [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded open set with smooth boundary. Here $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ are given parameters. The equation is supplemented with Dirichlet boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
u|_{\partial D} = 0
\end{equation}
and (smooth) initial conditions:
\begin{equation}
u(0) = u_0, \quad \partial_t u(0) = v_0.
\end{equation}
(i) Show that if $u^{(1)}$ and $u^{(2)}$ are smooth solutions of the damped Sine-Gordon equation with the same initial conditions, namely if
\begin{equation}
u^{(1)}(0,x) = u^{(2)}(0,x), \quad \partial_t u^{(1)}(0,x) = \partial_t u^{(2)}(0,x) \quad \text{for all } x \in D
\end{equation}
then $u^{(1)} = u^{(2)}$ on all of $D \times [0, \infty).$
(ii) Now suppose that $u^{(1)}$ and $u^{(2)}$ are any two smooth solutions of the damped Sine-Gordon equation subject to the above boundary condition. Show that there exists a constant $\rho > 0,$ depending only on $D,$ such that the quantity
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}(t) := \int_D \big[(\partial_t( u^{(1)}(t,x) - u^{(2)}(t,x))^2 + |\nabla(u^{(1)}(t,x) - u^{(2)}(t,x))|^2\big] dx
\end{equation}
with an exponential rate in time whenever
\begin{equation}
\frac{|\beta|}{\alpha} < \rho.
\end{equation}
Proof:
This is my proof for i) but I am not sure if it is correct and I am stuck on ii)
Let $w = u^{(1)} -u^{(2)}$ then $w$ satisfies:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{tt} w + \alpha \partial_t w - \Delta w + \beta [\sin(u^{(1)})-\sin(u^{(2)})] = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
w|_{\partial D} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
w(0,x) = \partial_t w(0,x) = 0
\end{equation}
Let $E(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle \int_{D}(w_t)^2+|\nabla w|^2dx$ then
\begin{align}
\dot{E}(t)&=\displaystyle\int_D w_t(w_{tt}-\Delta w))\\
& = -\alpha \displaystyle\int_D (w_t)^2dx -\beta \displaystyle\int_D (w_t)[\sin(u^{(1)})-\sin(u^{(2)})]\\
& \leq  -\alpha \displaystyle\int_D (w_t)^2dx +|\beta|\displaystyle\int_D |w||w_t|dx
\end{align}
Apply Young-$\varepsilon$ and Poincare's inequality for $|\beta| \displaystyle\int_D |w||w_t|dx$, we deduce
$$\dot{E}(t) \leq \left(\dfrac{|\beta|\varepsilon}{2}-\alpha \right)\displaystyle\int_D (w_t)^2dx +\dfrac{|\beta|C_0}{2\varepsilon} \displaystyle\int_D |\nabla w|^2dx$$
Choose $C = \max \{\dfrac{|\beta| \varepsilon}{2}-\alpha;\dfrac{|\beta|C_0}{2\varepsilon}\}$ then
$$\dot{E}(t) \leq C E(t)$$
By Gronwall's inequality,we get
$$E(t) \leq e^C.E(0)=0$$
Thus $E(t)=0,$ which implies $w=0$ then we complete the proof.
Am I correct for $i$?
And for ii) I thought that we can do the same like i), for $\rho$ we can choose $\rho = \max \{\dfrac{|\beta| \varepsilon}{2}-\alpha;\dfrac{|\beta|C_0}{2\varepsilon}; \dfrac{|\beta|}{\alpha}\}$ but the problem is $\rho$ is not only dependent on $D$ but also $\beta$ and $\alpha,$ which does not satisfy the requirement.
Could someone give me any better ideas? Because of ii) give the hint $\frac{|\beta|}{\alpha} <\rho$ , it makes me think my approach for i) may not be good. The constant $C$ I chose quite not well.
Hint:
The professor gave us the hint that:
For i) If $w = u^1 - u^2$ consider the equation satisfied by $v^\epsilon = \partial_t w + \epsilon w,$ for an $\epsilon > 0$ a parameter to be tuned.  Then try to do an $L^2$ type energy estimate for $v^\epsilon.$
So it is different from what I did in the proof. But I haven't yet figured out the hint.
For ii)
You can also add two simplifications here to this part of the problem 1) that the domain yields a Poincare constant of 1 to simply calculations and 2) that you only need to prove the exponential decay for $\beta < \rho \min\{\alpha, 1\}$ for an appropriate choice of rho (I think something like $\rho=1/2$ will do).  It's just playing with epsilon young's inequality to get an appropriate differential inequality to apply Gronwall.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
